# NRGridView won't show data from my core data database

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data, gridview

I am building a app for a local football club. I want to show all players names and pictures in a grid. Therefore I am using the NRGridview. But it won't load up with my data. I have an NSArray with all players information. Here you see the method which generates this array.

```
   - (NSArray *)getTeam
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Team"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortOrder" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *mutableFetchResults = [self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSLog(@"first error log %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        NSLog(@"second error log %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }else if ([mutableFetchResults count] == 0){
        NSLog(@"geen resultaten voor team");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"team names: %@",[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"name"]);
        return mutableFetchResults;
    }
    return mutableFetchResults;

}
```

And this is what I do in the tableview.

```
- (NRGridViewCell*)gridView:(NRGridView *)gridView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyCellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";

    NRGridViewCell* cell = [gridView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[NRGridViewCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];

        [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.]];
        [[cell detailedTextLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.]];

    }

    NSLog(@"players array %@",players);
    for (int i = 0; i <= [players count]; i++) {

       // NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[players objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"image"]]];
       // UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imgData];
        //cell.imageView.image = image;
        cell.textLabel.text = [[players objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"name"];
        cell.detailedTextLabel.text = [[players objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"position"];
        return cell;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

The NSLog gives always (null). My question is now, where should I put the code "`NSArray *players = [self getTeam]` . so that my tableview will fill up with data?

**EDIT**

It did give me back the right amount of sections, and numberOfRowsInsection. For numbersOfRowsIn section I created 4 methods. 1 method whichs gets all off the goalkeepers, 1 for the defenders, 1 for the wingers, and 1 for the attackers. Then In my tableview method I did the following.

```
- (NSInteger)gridView:(NRGridView *)gridView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0){
        return [[self getDoelmannen]count];
    }else if (section == 1){
        return [[self getVerdedigers]count];
    }else if (section == 2){
        return [[self getMiddenvelders]count];
    }else{
        return [[self getAanvallers]count];
    }
    return [[self getAanvallers]count];
}
```

This works. But still have the problem for my cell self.

**EDIT2**
Okay I think my problem is with filling my players Array up. I do the following in my viewDidLoad

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    _players = [self getTeam];
    NSLog(@"players array: %@",_players);
}
```

Which gives the following log.

```
2012-10-17 12:11:22.099 RacingGenk[63122:c07] nil
2012-10-17 12:11:22.099 RacingGenk[63122:c07] players array: (null)
```

Here is my code for getTeam

```
- (NSArray *)getTeam
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Team"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortOrder" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *mutableFetchResults = [self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        NSLog(@"nil");
    }else if ([mutableFetchResults count] == 0){
        NSLog(@"geen resultaten voor team");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"team names: %@",[mutableFetchResults valueForKey:@"name"]);
        return mutableFetchResults;
    }
    return mutableFetchResults;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `players` isn't getting initialized. You can put your `[self getTeam]` call in the `viewDidLoad` method and make `players` a property.

If `NRGridView` is anything like `UITableView`, there are probably other methods that you need to overload.

For example, `UITableView` has `tableView:numberOrRowsInSection:`. Failure to return > 0 value from this method results in nothing being shown. Or `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, which returns the number of sections and so on.

Check the documentation for the control you're using.

Update:

Since your `executeFetchRequest:error:` is failing, you should check if there's an error message instead of just printing out `(nil)`:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

Comment: Yes I've implemented this methods. And it gives back the right amount of sections and also the right amount of numbersOfRowsAtSections

Comment: I've tried that but still it won't fill up. Also tried it do to it in my viewWillAppear. But same result

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is with calling getTeam in the viewDidLoad. Look at my edited question please.

Comment: Do you know what the problem can be?

Comment: it just always returns (null)

Comment: I've updated my question with the new getTeam method with error logs. This is what I Get: 2012-10-17 13:46:09.661 RacingGenk[66600:c07] first error log (null)
2012-10-17 13:46:09.661 RacingGenk[66600:c07] second error log (null) I appreciated That you want to help me!

Comment: are you sure there is some actual data in your core data store?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure. But I fixed it with a different loop. But still thanks for your help.